# Do we need a canonical answer about ENOSPC?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Searching for [No space left on device](https://serverfault.com/search?q=No%20space%20left%20on%20device) finds 159 questions, and I didn't find any canonical among them. Do we need a canonical Q/A for that?

So far theses four reasons has covered all of the out of disk space questions I have come across:

- Large deleted file still in use
- File system ran out of inodes
- Remaining free space reserved for root
- Sub directory with large/many files hidden by mount point

Comment: While I like the idea (but don't think it necessarily needs a meta question) you might want to [tweak the query](http://serverfault.com/search?q=%22No+space+left+on+device%22+is%3Aquestion) to at least limit to questions, and perhaps utilize the exact text.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: This reminds me to write up one of the very few times ENOSPC has been given for none of the above reasons...

Comment: Another reason that I'm sure must have come up: filesystem with deduplication cannot delete a file that's also present in a snapshot

Comment: If there are still odd corner cases coming in, you may just want to make the answer CW and invite everyone to contribute.

Comment: Is one of the existing questions suitable to be made canonical? Or should I just write a new Q/A for it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes I think a canonical Q&A for ENOSPC. There are so many that turn up it can only be a good thing.